# turn on and off labels dynamically on linespoints based on the value of xrange

Tags: label, gnuplot

I am trying to turn on and off the labels programmatically based on the value of the `xrange`.

For example when I show only 1 week data then I would like to show the values but when I display 5 years data then I would like to hide the `labels`.

**Example 1: showing 1 week data range**

[image]

**Example 2: sowing a large data set**

[image]

**This is the relevant part of my code:**

```
...
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# plot historical data
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
if (exists("diagram_range_in_days")) {
    now = time(0)
    set xrange [now - (diagram_range_in_days * 24 * 60 * 60):now]

    if (diagram_range_in_days <=30) {
        set logscale y 3
    }
}

...

plot input_file using 1:column(col_a) with linespoints linestyle 5 title "aaa", \
     input_file using 1:col_b         with linespoints linestyle 6 title "bbb", \
     input_file using 1:col_c         with linespoints linestyle 1 title "ccc", \
             '' using 1:col_d:(sprintf("%'.0f", column(col_d))) with labels center offset 0, 1 notitle
```

My code works fine but I would like to control the showing/hiding labels from my code dynamically, the same way how I set `xrange` and `logscale` above based on the provided input by user.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer 1:**

For the code as shown, it would suffice to replace the line

```
'' using 1:col_d:(sprintf("%'.0f", column(col_d))) with labels center offset 0, 1 notitle
```

with

```
'' using (diagram_range_in_days < threshold ? $1 : NaN) : col_d : (sprintf("%'.0f", column(col_d))) \
            with labels center offset 0, 1 notitle
```

However that test would be invalidated if the plot is subsequently zoomed or rescaled by the user without reevaluating diagram_range_in_days.  That could probably be handled also with additional effort;  do you require that?

**Answer 2:**

A different approach that might be attractive if your graphs are viewed interactively is to switch the labels to hypertext rather than turning them off altogether.  That way one label at a time becomes visible on mouse-over.

Here I put the "hypertext" attribute in a string variable and expand it as a macro in the plot command:

```
if (diagram_range_in_days < threshold) {
    display_state = ""
} else {
    display_state = "hypertext"
}

plot ... \
   '' using 1:col_d:(sprintf("%'.0f", column(col_d))) \
      with labels @display_state offset 0,1 notitle
```

Comment: This WORKS: `entry=diagram_range_in_days <= threshold_days ? 1 : NaN`, then `using entry:...`, BUT this does NOT work: `using (diagram_range_in_days <= threshold_days ? 1 : NaN):...`. Strange.